# Kinetic JS - Loading GrayScale image

Tags: kineticjs, grayscale

I am trying to following this example to load grayscale image http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-grayscale-image-colors-tutorial/.  Since my stage has many other objects, I tried to use the follwing script:

```
var dImage1 = new Kinetic.Image({
                drawFunc: function (canvas) {
                    var context2 = canvas.getContext();
                    var x = 0;
                    var y = 0;
                    context2.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);
                    var imageData = context2.getImageData(x, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
                    var data = imageData.data;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
                        var brightness = 0.34 * data[i] + 0.5 * data[i + 1] + 0.16 * data[i + 2];
                        data[i] = brightness;
                        data[i + 1] = brightness;
                        data[i + 2] = brightness;
                    }
                    context2.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
                }
            });
            layer1.add(dImage1);
            stage.add(layer1);

            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function () {
                drawImage(this);
            };
            imageObj.src = .....;
```

I got this error: TypeMismatchError.  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of gotchas in your code...

First, even though the spec says it's optional, you need to specify the context mode ("2d")

```
// must specify "2d"

var context2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Second, you need to fully load your image before you use it in a Kinetic.Image

So put Kinetic.Image creation in a function and call it in imageObj.onload:

```
function makeKineticImage(){

    var dImage1 = new Kinetic.Image({
        drawFunc: function (canvas) {
            var context2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;
            context2.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);
            var imageData = context2.getImageData(x, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
            var data = imageData.data;

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
                var brightness = 0.34 * data[i] + 0.5 * data[i + 1] + 0.16 * data[i + 2];
                data[i] = brightness;
                data[i + 1] = brightness;
                data[i + 2] = brightness;
            }
            context2.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
        }
    });
    layer1.add(dImage1);
}

stage.add(layer1);

// you must create your Kinetic.Image AFTER your image is loaded

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function () {
    makeKineticImage();
};
imageObj.src = .....;
```

Comment: Mark, can I change the image width and height in this line:
context2.getImageData(x, y, dicom1.width, dicom1.height); to be
context2.getImageData(x, y, 512, 512); I tried but did not work.  Also how can I add offset value? thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Sure.  getImageData just gets a rectangular chunk of pixels starting at any X/Y.  So you can get a 512x512 square chunk of pixels at any offset X/Y you desire with getImageData(myOffsetX,myOffsetY,512,512).  If you're getting an error, make sure that you haven't requested pixels beyond the edges of your canvas...So, if your canvas is 1000x1000 and you do getImageData(700,700,512,512) you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks Mark, the offset worked but the image size did not; do I need to change as well putImageData?

Comment: I changed   context2.drawImage(dicom1, x, y, width, height); and it worked, thanks a million.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not need to pass the "2d" param into getContext().  The canvas parameter passed into the drawFunc function is not a canvas element, its a special KineticJS renderer.  the getContext() method returns the canvas element context

Comment: my bad...While I actually knew that about KineticJS, my mind incorrectly flashed to regular html canvas where it's required.  Thanks for the backup catching my glitch!  :)